# GetWindowRect Returns 1/4 Window Area

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, user32

When calling GetWindowRect, I get results that indicate the window is 1/4 its actual size.

I'm using Windows 10 with a 4K monitor, and some of the UI elements are scaled, I'm wondering if that could be contributing.

I don't really have any code or work to show, I'm just importing and calling the User32 function. The rect fields are declared in the correct order.

Can anyone let me know why the dimensions are incorrect? And perhaps how to scale them appropriately?

Comment: 2 close votes, 1 negative point, 0 comments. Classic.

Answer (score 3):

Your process needs to be marked as being DPI aware, something you do in the application manifest. Without doing so your application is subject to DPI virtualization. See: [Writing DPI-Aware Desktop and Win32 Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn469266.aspx)

Comment: Mmm. Thought this may be the case. I don't own the process. How can I know how it is being scaled?

Comment: The fact that your rect coordinates are not what you expect tell you that.

Comment: All I know is that they are incorrect... I'm trying to adjust them appropriately. Do you know how to discover the scaling factor?

Comment: I don't think that's easy. You are probably going about this the wrong way.

Comment: Why do you suppose this is the wrong approach? Can you suggest another way to capture the bounds of a window from another process, then?

Comment: Because inside the process, what can you do with the true coordinates. Every API that operates on coordinates is virtualized. Normally you'd use these virtualized coordinates. In fact you don't even ask a question. You just have some statements. So I've interpreted your question as asking why this happens. I don't think I can suggest a solution without knowing the problem. That surely is another question. Since the entire issue is new to you I believe you need to step back, take some time to study the issue of DPI virtualization, and take stock. Looking for solutions is premature.

Comment: I think you're being rather presumptive, and maybe a bit rude. I think the question was implied 'why am I getting the incorrect coordinates.' That is the problem. 'Every' API uses virtualized coords? Please reference GDI32 library to see your error. Who you gonna call? Not David Heffernan. Thanks anyway, I've already figured out how to retrieve factor to adjust dimensions.

Comment: That was what I took the question to be. Hence the answer. This is a complex issue. If it's brand new to you then expect it to take some time to master. Your solution accounts for per monitor dpi?

Comment: For sure it is complex. I don't intend to master it today. I've only been able to get to the system dpi settings for now, but it is enough to move me forward. For what it's worth, it was another one of your answers from several years ago that got me where I needed to be. Thanks.

Comment: We disagree quite fundamentally here. Which is fine. Good luck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111062/discussion-between-michael-and-david-heffernan).

Comment: @Michael: The marking as DPI-aware matters for the process calling `GetWindowRect`, not the process which owns the window.

Answer (score 1):

Use `DwmGetWindowAttribute` with `DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS` in `dwAttribute` parameter.
This should give you the real size of the window in pixels unit.
Read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwmapi/nf-dwmapi-dwmgetwindowattribute